# Want to change color of post<h1> title if it has no featured image set for that post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

So on my wordpress blog *and most* other wordpress blogs, you can set a featured image. If you don't set a featured image I have it default to a background image that says "new update" however the default background image i have set is much less eye grabbing than the custom ones made for the post.

To solve the issue of posts with custom featured images getting more attention that those that have the default image - I would like to make it so all blog post titles with posts that do not have a featured image to change their color code.

For example something like..

**My pseudo code:** - I'm don't know jquery/javascript very well but I could probably figure out the basic javascript to make it work.

```
IF 
('post > featured-image') = 'NONE'; 

THEN ('.post-list h1.entry-title a') = 'RED';

ELSE ('.post-list h1.entry-title a') = 'DEFAULT';
```

But that being said **how would i even reference** the POST not having a FEATURED IMAGE in **wordpress** via jquery or some function? I am open to any solutions!

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: it would probably be better to handle this at render time in your PHP, and apply a class to the title, then style it with css, rather than trying a JS solution. Could you please post the PHP code you have that outputs the entry titles.

Comment: I am just really good at breaking PHP haha. So i thought a JS solution would be best. My main question is how to even reference the POST not having a featured image set.

Do you know what that would look like? Even in php?

Comment: You would make a call to [`get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) and check if it returns anything. Im happy to help if you can post the code you have

Comment: I appreciate it thanks! My thought is however. If you have to call in the post ID than the post would have to be made before the function was made correct? because the ID for the post wouldnt exist yet.

This wouldnt work because I am trying to make it automatic. So if a post is posted with no featured image initially and instantly updates the <h1> css based on the h1 class.

Comment: Ok, so when that page loads, each of those posts that are visible, is being rendered based off what Wordpress calls [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) inside your theme. We can make a check at the point in the loop where it creates the `h1` and apply a class to it based upon the presence of the thumbnail/featured image. Then in your css file you just make a style declaration for the corresponding class and do what you like with it. _PS_ they really shouldnt be `h1`s given there are more than 1 of them on the page at once too

Comment: I realize multiple h1 tags on a specific post page is bad for SEO however I didnt realize it mattered on an archive page? Where every listed blog on an archive or category page has a h1 title. I thought that was normal no? What should it be if u dont mind me asking?

As for your suggestion on how to accomplish my initial issue -  yes that's exactly what I need to happen! :) I donno how to pull off that script though or how to find one i can edit. Im usually okay at editing scripts.

Comment: its my understanding, that its also bad for screen readers/accessibility. Using css you can style just about any element to look the same, but hierarchically speaking, an `h2` would be fine. If you have admin access to your site, head to `Appearance -> Editor` and see if you can locate something like `index.php` ,`blog.php`, `archive.php` or `category.php`, any one of those is likely to be supplying the template for the page, but depending upon your theme could be called any number of things

Comment: Sure np! So i need to access the page that displays my blogs and locate the featured image function?

Were you referring to my initial problem/post in the last part of your comment?

Thanks!

Comment: Featured images are a default feature in WordPress. So my sites setup wouldn't be unique from any other WordPress setup as far as my featured image and H1 tag function issue goes.

Comment: We dont need to create a custom function for this, its a straightforward `if:else` statement, i just need to know what the loop looks like for your theme in order to post the edits you'll need to make

Comment: Oh ok leme find it - just a min

Comment: Here's the code for the page you were referring too. I just put it in a txt file and put it on my server. http://portalpacific.net/overflow/content.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you supplied your theme is already checking for the presence of a thumbnail on your posts using the wordpress function `has_post_thumbnail`. We can leverage this existing `if:else` statement to change a string value that we will apply to our `h1` tags. You can find the string value under the variable `$header_class_name`.

1. First we default the value to "has-thumbnail" (`Line 18`)
2. Then we override the default to "no-thumbnail" in the event that the post has no thumbnail (`Line 33`)
3. Lastly, we apply the class to the `h1` tag (`Line 72`)

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template part for displaying content.
 *
 * @package azera-shop
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( apply_filters( 'azera_shop_content_post_class_filter','border-bottom-hover' ) ); ?> itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

    <header class="entry-header">

            <div class="post-img-wrap">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >

                    <?php
                    // default the $header_class_name to 'has-thumbnail'
                    $header_class_name = 'has-thumbnail';
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $image_url_big = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id,'azera-shop-post-thumbnail-big', true );
                    $image_url_mobile = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id,'azera-shop-post-thumbnail-mobile', true );
                    ?>
                    <picture itemscope itemprop="image">
                    <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="<?php echo esc_url( $image_url_mobile[0] ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_url_big[0] ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    </picture>
                    <?php
                    } else {
                    // override the default $header_class_name in the case that there is no thumbnail
                    $header_class_name = 'no-thumbnail';
                    ?>
                    <picture itemscope itemprop="image">
                    <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="<?php echo azera_shop_get_file( '/images/no-thumbnail-mobile.jpg' );?> ">
                    <img src="<?php echo azera_shop_get_file( '/images/no-thumbnail.jpg' ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    </picture>
                    <?php } ?>

                </a>
                <?php azera_shop_post_date_index_box_trigger(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="entry-meta list-post-entry-meta">
                <?php azera_shop_content_entry_meta_top_trigger(); ?>
                <span itemscope itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="entry-author post-author">
                    <span  itemprop="name" class="entry-author author vcard">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><a itemprop="url" class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" rel="author"><?php the_author(); ?> </a>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="posted-in entry-terms-categories">
                    <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php _e( 'Posted in','azera-shop' ); ?> 
                    <?php
                        /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
                        $categories_list = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ', ', 'azera-shop' ) );
                        $pos = strpos( $categories_list, ',' );
                    if ( $pos ) {
                        echo substr( $categories_list, 0, $pos );
                    } else {
                        echo $categories_list;
                    }
                    ?>
                </span>
                <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" class="post-comments">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php comments_number( esc_html__( 'No comments','azera-shop' ), esc_html__( 'One comment','azera-shop' ), esc_html__( '% comments','azera-shop' ) ); ?>
                </a>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

        <?php 
            // add the $header_class_name value to the h1 (PS consider using a similarly styled h2)
            the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title '.$header_class_name.'" itemprop="headline"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'azera_shop_header_underline','<div class="colored-line-left"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>' ); ?>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div itemprop="description" class="entry-content entry-summary">
        <?php
            $ismore = strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->' );
        if ( $ismore ) : the_content( sprintf( esc_html__( 'Read more %s &#8230;','azera-shop' ), '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'about ', 'azera-shop' ) . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</span>' ) );
            else : the_excerpt();
            endif;
        ?>

        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'azera-shop' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

**CSS**

```
article header h1.no-thumbnail{
    color:red;
}
```

You can then apply CSS by referencing either class name

Comment: Sweet. leme try to apply it. Thanks!

Comment: Its working cuz i see the classes added correctly in dev tools!! :D :D 

The css is being funny but ill figure that out in a min. THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much! Works just how I needed.

Answer (score 2):

on your `single.php`  file, or  the page you use to display the single blog post you need to to an if statement check if the post have a thumbnail then if it does printout the style, or else let the default style will take place

```
<?php

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();

   echo "<style type=\"text/css\">";

    echo ".post-list h1.entry-title a{

            color: red !important ; /*any color of your choice*/;
        }
</style>";

}
else {

    // Default style will take place
}
?>
```

**Make sure that you add thumbnail support on your functions.php file.**

To add thumbnail support on your functions.php just add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Comment: How do i add thumbnail support in functions.php?

I placed that php function into my my content.php which has my post-image and title info. It turned all posts h1 tags red. Instead of just the ones without a featured image. 

You can see live in the link referenced in the comments above.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Thumbs up for now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
<header class="entry-header">
```

with

```
<header class="entry-header <?= has_post_thumbnail() ? 'my-hasfeatured-img' : '' ?>">
```

and then add CSS rule in *style.css* like:

```
.my-hasfeatured-img h1{
    //your code
}
```

Hope this helps!